# Sonarqube upgrade 5.6 to 6.1, test coverage measue is missing

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I just upgraded my sonar installation from 5.6 to 6.1.
Before the database had test coverage for java projects and the measures associated.
If I go to a project the page of the project only shows Bugs&vulnerabilites, code smells and duplications.
Even after rerunning the coverage with jenkins (same method as previous run) the coverage is not shown. Jenkins do report coverage as usual. 
Also no test coverage info is shown in the code.

I verified: 
- Installation is done correctly. Database upgrade is done correctly
- Look at not rerun projects (no test coverage)
- Rerun one project, test coverage not to be seen in that project 
- Jenkins does report test coverage
- I upgraded the sonar plugin from 2.4.1 to 2.5 and rerun the analysis. No test coverage available.

The sonar.junit.reportsPath does point to the jacoco.exec file
In the same directory a lot of TEST....txt files are present (no xml)

What am I missing? It worked in 5.6.

Comment: Found the problem, I was missing the sonar.java.binaries. Sonar-5.6 did not need those

Comment: I was with the same problem. I did the upgrade to sonarqube 6.1 and It does not recover the coverage report from cobertura. It locates the report cobertura.xml but It does not understand the coverage version 2.1.1.